# How to move bundles generated with ng serve of Angular Application?

Tags: angular, directory, angular-cli, bundle, serve

I need to move files of bundles generated with `ng serve` (not `ng build`!), of Angular Application, into specific directory.
The bundles generated with `ng serve` are:

```
vendor.js             
polyfills.js          
styles.css
styles.js 
main.js               
runtime.js
```

I would like to move these files into directory:

```
<directory>/vendor.js             
<directory>/polyfills.js          
<directory>/styles.css
<directory>/styles.js 
<directory>/main.js               
<directory>/runtime.js
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that anymore - see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1962#issuecomment-247509283.

But maybe `fileReplacements` might help you: https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements

Comment: Can I rename files of bundles? For Example: main.js => main.application.js

Comment: I think so, yes - I edited my answer (added a link to fileReplacements).